# how to connect android application and openstack cloud?

Tags: android, android-activity, openstack, openstack-horizon

I have setup an openstack cloud and I am able to upload/download the files through browser (logging through "horizon" dashboard) of android device,  but i want to build an android app to directly connect to and transact with the cloud. 
Is there any APIs? 
Which method can i take? 
Please revert back. Any solution would be helpful. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to connect to the API. Every OpenStack instance has an accessible REST API which allows you to make HTTP requests.
 [OpenStack Rest API](http://developer.openstack.org/api-ref.html)

There are also numerous SDK's to connect to the API programmatically: [See here](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/SDKs)